# Are these LEGO pieces original? How can I be sure?

Tags: part-identification, technic

When I enter in the code on the BrickLink site the codes come up, but there are no markings on the tires suggesting the name of the company or any code. Could it still be an original piece if this is the case?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For the rim I would say its original.

- LEGO made this part in [Transparent](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-6053875).
- It has the correct mound ID [88517](https://brickset.com/parts/design-88517)
- And contains the LEGO logo + copyright symbol

Only this part comes in 2 sets which doesn't contain a tire.

The tire you have looks like [Motorcycle Tyre Ø 100,6](https://brickset.com/parts/6021952/motorcycle-tyre-%C3%B8-100-6). Based on photos I cannot see any visible markings on the outside of the tire. I do own a couple of these tires myself but don't have access to them at the moment. So I can't check if there are any markings on the inside of the tire.

If I check for example the Bugatti or the Harley-Davidson tire, all the id stuff that is not mentioned on the outside, is on the inside. See picture below of the small tire used in the Harley-Davidson.

So you can check the inside for any markings telling you if its an original part or not.

[image]

Comment: thanks for information. i bought the tires and rims in one package. tires don't have any id markings inside or outside but ve have a qr code on the package which is 6172059.

Comment: QR code on a package has nothing to do with parts inside.